# importing modules : no module named

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

I'm a bit new to python and i have a programming project to complete.
My python version is 2.7.6
I want to call upon a_x,a_y and a_z functions in another module.
Here are my two modules.

**`Module 1`**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt 
import math
a=0.5
b=0.1


def N(x,y,z):
    return 1 + x**2 + y**2/a**2 + z**2/b**2

def a_x(x,y,z):
    return -(220**2)*x/ N(x,y,z)
def a_y(x,y,z):
    return -(220**2)*y/(N(x,y,z)*a**2)
def a_z(x,y,z):
    return -(220**2)*z/(N(x,y,z)*b**2)
```

**Module 2**

```
import D2baanvergelijkingen
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

begin_x = 1 
begin_y = 2
begin_z = 3

func=[a_x(x,y,z),a_y(x,y,z),a_z(x,y,z)]

def y0(begin_x,begin_y,begin_z):
    y0=[begin_x,begin_y,begin_z]
    return y0

Dfun = 3.08567756705*10**19

args= (x,y,z)

t=np.linspace(0,10,1000)

I=odeint(func,y0,t,args,Dfun)

plt.plot(t, I[:,0])
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

As you can see i try to run my second module, but then i just get No module named D2baanvergelijkingen. This is what's my module 1 is called (yes i'm from belguim).
So i can't get my functions into the second module which is necessary!

Answer (score 0):

To import a module in python it must me in the PATH system variable (both Windows and Linux), or it has to be in the same folder where you are running the second script..
ex: Module 2 has to be in the same folder as D2baanvergelijkingen